# Gtk Derived Widgets or Templates

Tags: python, pygobject

Does PyGI have derived widgets (like C++) or have template widgets (Like C), and how to use ?

The intention is to subclass `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` and then bind to Builder definition UI.